Unable to find nearby places in android studio using Java
I am working on an Android project and I want to search for nearby places(for example hospital), but this code doesn't work.
From what I saw in debugging mode, it skips this line: placesClient.findCurrentPlace(request).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FindCurrentPlaceResponse>()
and of course also the code that is below this line.
Anyone have idea why? You can see the whole code below.
    Places.initialize(this, getString(R.string.google_maps_key));
    PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

    List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.NAME);
    FindCurrentPlaceRequest request = FindCurrentPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeFields);
    placesClient.findCurrentPlace(request).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FindCurrentPlaceResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FindCurrentPlaceResponse> task) {
                    FindCurrentPlaceResponse response = task.getResult();
                    for(PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : response.getPlaceLikelihoods()){
                        Place place = placeLikelihood.getPlace();
                        List<Place.Type> types = place.getTypes();
                        if(types != null && types.contains(Place.Type.HOSPITAL)){
                            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(place.getLatLng())
                                    .title(place.getName())
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


Removed android-studio tag as that tag is for questions/issues related to the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do wit Android Studio.

Use "step into" in the debugger (or add logging) and find out what placesClient.findCurrentPlace(request) returns.

I don't understand what do you mean...
It doesn't show me what this line returns

Your OnCompleteListener will be called at some time in the future when the task completes. The onComplete() method isn't called immediately. This whole API is an asynchronous API, so things don't happen immediately. How long did you wait before deciding that it wasn't getting called?

Things to check:
First, carefully check logcat as you might be hitting API key set issues or permissions errors.  It is common to have issues with both of these.
Second, either set a debug breakpoint with the OnCompleteListener or add a Log message that you can find in logcat.  The goal here is to ensure the callback is being called.  In the provided code snippet does nothing that would be apparent unless a hospital is found.
Third, consider updating the camera to ensure the view is focused on the results.

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        com.example.playground.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    // Normal, you should check that the app has the required permissions.
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    void getCurrentPlace() {
        String apiKey = BuildConfig.PLACES_API_KEY;

        Places.initialize(this, apiKey);
        PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

        List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG);
        FindCurrentPlaceRequest request = FindCurrentPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeFields);

        placesClient.findCurrentPlace(request)
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    FindCurrentPlaceResponse response = task.getResult();

                    LatLngBounds.Builder bounds = LatLngBounds.builder();

                    for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : response.getPlaceLikelihoods()) {
                        Place place = placeLikelihood.getPlace();
                        Log.e("PlacesDemo", "Found place: " + place.getName());

                        List<Place.Type> types = place.getTypes();
                        if (types != null && types.contains(Place.Type.STORE)) {
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(Objects.requireNonNull(place.getLatLng()))
                                    .title(place.getName())
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
                        } else {
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(Objects.requireNonNull(place.getLatLng()))
                                    .title(place.getName())
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));
                        }

                        if (place.getLatLng() != null)
                            bounds.include(place.getLatLng());
                    }
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds.build(), 100));
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(task -> {
                    String message = task.getMessage();
                    Log.e("PlacesDemo", message);
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        getCurrentPlace();
    }
}

